# Firebase: Why value event gets fired before new child ref gets added

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2

Following code, is a very simple Firebase - VueJS app, ([codeSandBox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/quotes-app-firebase-vuejs-j6w24))

**app.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Adding Quote -->
    <add-quote/>

    <!-- Display Quotes -->
    <quote-list/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import addQuote from "./components/AddQuote.vue";
import quoteList from "./components/QuoteList.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    addQuote,
    quoteList
  },
  methods: {
    get_allQuotes: function() {
      // var vm = this;
      var localArr = [];
      quotesRef
        .once("value", function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(snap) {
            localArr.push({
              key: snap.key,
              category: snap.val().category,
              quoteTxt: snap.val().quoteTxt
            });
          });
        })
        .then(data => {
          this.$store.commit("set_allQuotes", localArr);
        });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.get_allQuotes();
    console.log("App: mounted fired");
  }
};
</script>
```

**store.js(vuex store)**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        quotesList: []
    },
    getters: {
        get_quotesList(state) {
            return state.quotesList;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        set_allQuotes(state, value) {
            state.quotesList = value;
        }
    }
});
```

**AddQuote.vue**

```
<template>     
    <div class="row quote-edit-wrapper">         
        <div class="col-xs-6">           
            <textarea v-model.lazy="newQuoteTxt" 
                rows="4" 
                cols="50"></textarea>
            <button @click="addQuote">Add Quote</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {   
  data() {
    return {
            newQuoteTxt: '',
      }
    },
    computed: {
    allQuotes() {
      return this.$store.getters.get_quotesList;
        },
        newQuoteIdx() {
            var localArr = [...this.allQuotes]

            if(localArr.length > 0) {
                var highestKEY, currKEY

                localArr.forEach((element, idx) => {
                    currKEY = parseInt(element.key)
                    if(idx == 0) {
                        highestKEY = currKEY
                    } else {
                        if(highestKEY < currKEY) {
                            highestKEY = currKEY
                        }
                    }
                })
                return highestKEY + 1
            } else {
                return 1
            }
        }
    },
  methods: {
        // ADD new Quote in DB
    addQuote: function() {
            var vm = this
            var localArr = [...this.allQuotes]

            //1. First attach 'value' event listener,
            // Snapshot will contain data from that ref 
            // when any child node is added/updated/delete
            quotesRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
                snapshot.forEach(function(snap) {
                var itemExists = localArr.some(function (item, idx) {
                        return item.key == snap.key
                    })
                // If newly added item doesn't yet exists then add to local array
                if (!(itemExists)) {
                    localArr.push({
                        key: snap.key,
                        category: snap.val().category,
                        quoteTxt: snap.val().quoteTxt })

                    vm.$store.commit('set_allQuotes', localArr)
                    }
                })
            })

            //2. Second set/create a new quotes in Firebase, 
            // When this quote gets added in Firebase,
            // value event (attached earlier) gets fired  
            //  with 
            var newQuoteRef = quotesRef.child(this.newQuoteIdx)
            newQuoteRef.set({
                category: 'motivation',
                quoteTxt: this.newQuoteTxt
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**quoteList.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 quotes-list-wrapper">
            <template v-for="(quote,idx) in allQuotes">

                <!-- Quote block -->
                    <div class="quote-block-item">
                        <p class="quote-txt"> {{quote.quoteTxt}} </p>
                    </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>  
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            allQuotes() {
                return this.$store.getters.get_quotesList;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

**Note:** The main code of concern is of **addQuote.vue**

User enter `newQuoteTxt` that gets added to Firebase (`addQuote()`) as a quote item under `quotesRef`. As soon as quote is added (on firebase), Firebase client side SDK's `value` event fires, and adds the new quote (via callback) to localArray (`allQuotes`). VueJS then updates the DOM with newly added Quote.

The `addQuote()` method works in the following manner:

1. First, attach a callback/listener to 'value' event on quotesRef

```
quotesRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
   ....
})
```

2. Next, A firebase ref (child of `quotesRef`) is created with a ID `this.newQuoteIdx`

   `var newQuoteRef = quotesRef.child(this.newQuoteIdx)`

Then `set()` is called (on this newly created Ref) adding newquote to firebase RealTime DB.

3. `value` event gets triggered (attached from step 1) and listener /callback is called.

The callback looks for this new quote's key in existing list of items by matching keys of localArr and `snap.key`, if not found, adds the newly quote to localArr.  localArr commits to a vuex store.

```
`vm.$store.commit('set_allQuotes', localArr)`
```

VueX then updates all subscriber component of this array. VueJS then adds the new quote to the existing list of quotes (updates the DOM)

While debugging the `addQuote` method, the problem I notice, the execution/flow of script (via F8 in chrome debugger) first steps into the listener/callback attached to `value` event before the code `newQuoteRef.set({ ... })` that adds new quote (on firebase), which in turn will cause 'value' event to trigger.

I am not sure why this occurs. Can anybuddy explain why the listener/callback is called before the quotes is created.

Are child nodes (of QuotesRef) are cached at clientside such that 'value' fires even before new quote is added.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question (Your code is not extremely easy to follow! :-)) it is the normal behaviour. As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#on):

> The value event **will trigger *once with the initial data* stored at
> this location**, and then **trigger again each time the data
> changes**.

Your sandbox demo does not actually shows how the app works, but normally you should not set-up the listener in the method that saves a new node to the database. These two things should be decoupled.

One common approach is to set the listener in the `created` hook of a component (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) and then in your `addQuote` method you just write to the database. As soon as you write, the listener will be fired.